# OOP jQuery set swipe eventlistener in prototype function

Tags: javascript, oop, jquery-mobile, event-handling, slider

i want to set up my tiny slider as class but I have a hard time setting the eventlisteners for swipe and click.
I just cant bind the events to my methods.

the eventlistener on "click" -> this.slideTo(targetslide) just spits out "this.slideTo is not a function" apparently I reference the method of my object incorrectly. ?

I would highly appreciate any hints as to why this isnt working and how to solve this issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 mySlider = new teamSlider();
 mySlider.initSlider();
});

function teamSlider(){
 console.log("teamSlider");
 this.slides_amount = 1;
 this.current_slide = 1;
 this.val_left = 0;
}

teamSlider.prototype = {
 constructor: teamSlider,
 initSlider:function() {
  this.slides_amount = $('.wrap-slide-game').length;
  // set size of elements according to slide numbers
  $('.slider-holder').css("width", this.slides_amount*100 + "%");
  $('.wrap-slide-game').css("width", 100/this.slides_amount + "%");
  $('.slider-idf:nth-child(1)').toggleClass("active");

  // EVENTLISTENER Swipe
  $('.slider-holder').on("swipeleft", this.slideLeft);
  $('.slider-holder').on("swiperight", this.slideRight);

  // EVENTLISTENER Indicator click
  $('.slider-idf').each(function(index){
   $(this).on("click",function() {
    this.slideTo(index+1)}
   );
  });
 },
 slideLeft:function() {
  if (this.current_slide < this.slides_amount) {
   // set current identifier inactive
   $('.slider-idf:nth-child('+this.current_slide+')').toggleClass("active");
   // move slides
   this.val_left -= 100;
   $('.slider-holder').css("left",this.val_left+"%");
   this.current_slide ++;
   $('.slider-idf:nth-child('+this.current_slide+')').toggleClass("active");
  }
 },
 slideRight:function() {
  if (this.current_slide > 1) {
   // set current identifier inactive
   $('.slider-idf:nth-child('+this.current_slide+')').toggleClass("active");
   this.val_left += 100;
   // move slides
   $('.slider-holder').css("left",this.val_left+"%");
   this.current_slide--;
   $('.slider-idf:nth-child('+this.current_slide+')').toggleClass("active");
  }
 },
 slideTo:function(targetslide) {
  $('.slider-idf:nth-child('+current_slide+')').toggleClass("active");
  this.val_left = -(targetslide-1)*100;
  $('.slider-holder').css("left",val_left+"%");
  this.current_slide = targetslide;
  $('.slider-idf:nth-child('+this.current_slide+')').toggleClass("active");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a coffee break works wonders.
the issue was simply that i was using they keyword "this" to reference the instanced object.

this works fine in the prototype function but inside the eventhandler "this" no longer references the object but the dom element the listener is being set on.

by setting my custom variable _this to my instanced object i can use it to call its functions inside the eventhandlers.

maybe this is useful for somebody somewhere. :)

```js
var _this = this;

// EVENTLISTENER Swipe
$('.slider-holder').on("swipeleft", function(){
  _this.slideLeft();
});
$('.slider-holder').on("swiperight", function(){
  _this.slideRight();
});

// EVENTLISTENER Indicator click
$('.slider-idf').each(function(index){
  $(this).on("click",function() {
    _this.slideTo(index+1)
  });
});
```